# Error when trying to retrieve class attributes.

Tags: python

I am relatively new to Python, and trying to understand a function I came across, by re-writing it and trying to running on jupyter. The purpose of the function is to analyse the calling class, retrieve properties associated with it, and create string that will be part of a query that will later be run against the database. 
I have created to very simple classes and added some attributes/properties to it, but I am getting an error which I am not sure how to resolve it:

```
class Person(object):

def __init__(self):
    pass
class Employee(Person):

    __required_properties__ = ['first_name', 'last_name']

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

def inherited_labels(cls):
    return ['employee']

def build_merge_query(cls, merge_params, update_existing=False, lazy=False, relationship=None):
    query_params = dict(merge_params=merge_params)
    print (query_params)
    n_merge = "n:{} {{{}}}".format(
        ":".join(cls.inherited_labels()),
        ", ".join("{0}: params.create.{0}".format(getattr(cls, p).db_property or p) 
              for p in cls.__required_properties__))
return n_merge

merge_params = ('first_name', 'last_name')

myEmployee = Employee()

build_merge_query(myEmployee, merge_params)
```

When I run this I got an "Attribute Error: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'first_name'

```
<ipython-input-78-2973503b3f7a> in <genexpr>(.0)
 21         ":".join(cls.inherited_labels()),
 22         ", ".join("{0}: params.create.{0}".format(getattr(cls, p).db_property or p) 
---> 23                   for p in cls.__required_properties__))
 24     return n_merge
 25 AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'first_name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to do, but here is my suggestion.
When you initialize the class, in your **init** class, you could add attribute to a class.
Here is an example for Person class.

```
class Person(first_name, last_name):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
       self.first_name = first_name
       self.last_name = last_name
```

By doing so, your Person class has attributes first_name and last_name. You could easily access them by calling myPerson.first_name, myPerson.last_name.

I guess this is what you want? Hope this help.